# Which OAuth flow to use for mobile app passwordless login

Tags: authentication, mobile, oauth, backend

The "passwordless login" term may not be accurate, but I don't know how to describe it. What I mean by that is a login that you see on a lot of fintech/crypto apps. Basically, the app has 4-digit local PIN (that's never sent to the API) and with this PIN, the long-lived refresh_token is encrypted.

The PIN is only remembered in the user's brain. So, next time you open the app, you just type your 4-digit PIN for login (or biometry), and the app will use refresh_token from there.

**Question:** Which OAuth flow would be appropriate for this? It seems that for login they all want password or show a prompt for the username/password. Or, they redirect to webpage which is not an option for mobile app.

What I need is some kind of request, that's only used when **signing up**, where I only send email (without password) and I get a long-lived refresh_token for that user. From there I can just refresh that same token over and over.

Comment: WebauthN is what you are searching for: https://webauthn.guide/

Comment: @jwilleke I'm looking for something that works with OAuth, not a completely different new standard. I doubt apps like Revolut, N26, Nexo all use WebAuthN. I will check it out further, thanks.

Comment: @jwilleke Specifically problem with webauthn is that it ties directly biometric login, while in these apps the biometric is not required. You can login just with 4-digit pin.

Comment: webauthn is that does not tie to any particular method. The WebAuthn standard is designed to enable communicators between an authenticator and a Relying Party. 
All major browsers implement the WebAuthn API, and most implement support for the CTAP and older U2F standards to varying degrees.
It only requires an Authenticator (Device). Windows Hello is an implementation of a webauthn and can only require a PIN.